# Is it possible to determine default values of optional parameters in a COM interop type?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, com

I am using C# 4.0 to instantiate an `Excel.Application` and open an `Excel.Workbook`. Stripped down, my code looks like this:

```
Excel.Application xlApp;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;

xlApp = new Excel.Application();
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("someFile");
```

The `Open()` method has a load of optional values that I do not need to provide. That is convenient, except that I do not know what the default values for those optional parameters are. As such, I can not decide whether or not I have to provide a value.

In this case, I can find the desired information for *some* parameters in the MSDN documentation. Is there a generic way to determine the default values for optional parameters in a COM interop type?

**UPDATE:**

Using `oleview` on `MSO.dll`, I checked out the corresponding IDL for the `Workbook` interface. For the `SaveAs()` method, it looks like this:

```
HRESULT SaveAs(
    [in, optional] VARIANT Filename,
    [in, optional] VARIANT FileFormat,
    [in, optional] VARIANT Password,
    blahblah...
    [in, optional, defaultvalue(1)] XlSaveAsAccessMode AccessMode,
    blahblah...
    [in, optional] VARIANT Local,
    [in, lcid] long lcid);
```

In Visual Studio, intellisense shows `[object Filename = Type.Missing]` for most parameters, which I guess makes sense because the IDL does not give any information about type (`VARIANT`) nor about any default value. For the parameter `AccessMode` however, the IDL provides the required information and intellisense shows it.

So I guess the question now becomes: why is the IDL not more specific about the type (and default value) of all parameters, just like it is for `AccessMode`?

Comment: Doesn't intellisense show th expected value?

Comment: @MBen: see my addition to the question under UPDATE for an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why is the IDL not more specific about the type (and default value)

It *is* specific about the type, it is VARIANT.  It doesn't *have* to be specific about the default value, a variant is capable of specifying "not specified".  Actually specifying the default value in the type library is possible, you saw that from the reverse-engineered IDL.

Lots of flexibility here.  But if the variant value is "not specified" then the COM server will substitute whatever value it considers the default or give specific behavior to it not being specified.  The only way to find out what that might be is through the documentation.  Which indeed isn't always stellar.

Comment: OK, got it. Now since these are `VARIANT` parameters it does not *have* to be specific about the default value, but *can* it be specific about the default value? In other words, is it possible to specify the default value for a `VARIANT` type parameter?

Comment: No, a variant itself doesn't carry a default value.  A specific default value can only be specified in the type library with the [defaultvalue] attribute in the method declaration.  It is the job of the compiler to create a variant with that value if the source code omits a value.

Comment: Not sure whether I fully understand your explanation, so I will reword my question. In the `SaveAs()` example, would it be technically possible to have `[in, optional, defaultvalue("workbook.xls")] VARIANT Filename` as opposed to `[in, optional] VARIANT Filename`?

Comment: Technically yes.  It is of course not actually present in the type library nor do you have an option to add it.

Comment: Now I understand, so in this case the creator of the COM object (=Microsoft team) decided for some reason not to include (all) default values in the interface. That is counter-intuitive to me. On second thought though, even knowing the default value still does not guarantee that you actually understand the corresponding behavior, and as user of the object I am *supposed* to read the documentation anyway to get the full understanding of the methods -- with or without default values.

Comment: What's relevant for a lack of specified default values is that COM method calls can be late bound.  Not that uncommon with Office apps, especially when used from scripting languages since they only support late binding.  No type library, so no source for default values.

Comment: But that would not prohibit providing the default values in the type library for those that *do* have access to it, would it?